# The UIView rotation in the overlay layer of camera controller view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, layer, addsubview

I am writing an application about the Augmented Reality.
In the CameraOverlayView, i have made a AR layer, which works fine.
I have planned the layer can be rotate, based on the iPhone orientation,
and its works fine.

However, I want to add some UIView elements on it, e.g. Radar, Slider.
For example, the Layer of AR = L0, I add the radar view, called L1, using

```
[augViewController.view addSubview:radarView];
```

L2 --do not want to rotate,L1 --do not want to rotate,L0 --want to rotate

The radarView will follow the rotation of the AR layer L0....I want the upper layer stay static.

How can it be done ??

Answer (score 0):

You should apply rotation to top views to nullify the rotation made by the bottom view.